# Network manager start access point

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager, realtek

I have a pcDuino and I need to start a access point using network-manager. I know this can be done by creating a new connection and setting the mode to `ap`. It says that this mode is not supported but I know other people have done it. The driver included with the kernel is `8192cu`. But running `lshw -C network` gives this:

```
  *-network:1
   description: Wireless interface
   physical id: 2
   bus info: usb@1:1
   logical name: wlan5
   serial: cc:d2:9b:5d:df:88
   capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8188eu ip=192.168.1.13 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

Anyone know how I can set up a `ap` using network-manager?

Answer (score 2):

You can try, using commands in the terminal.

You need at least: Wireless PCI or USB device connected to Linux with a/b/g and WPA2 support in AP mode, suppose it is `wlan0` and Wired ethernet port connected to the upstream router for the Internet access, suppose it is `eth0`.

Open a terminal. **(Ctrl+Alt+T)**.

Type the following command to install the application:

```
$ sudo -i
# apt-get update
# apt-get install hostapd bridge-utils
```

Now you must configure it by editing your file /etc/default/hostapd

```
$ sudo -i
# nano /etc/default/hostapd
```

Uncomment and set DAEMON_CONF to the absolute path of a hostapd configuration file:

DAEMON_CONF="/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf"

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, save file. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, close nano.

Now you need to create the text file /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf

```
sudo -i
nano /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
```

You must place these lines:

```
# Wireless network name - Set interface name

interface=wlan0

# Bridge name - set your bridge name

bridge=br0

# Driver nane - set driver name

driver=rtl8188eu

# Country name code - set country name code in ISO/IEC 3166-1 format. US = United Stats 

country_code=US

# SSID name - set your SSID

ssid=TameHog

# Operation mode - set operation mode a=IEEE 802.11a, b=IEEE 802.11b, g=IEEE 802.11g

hw_mode=g

# Channel number - set channel number

channel=3

# wpa mode - set wpa mode to 2

wpa=2

# wpa-passphrase - set your passphrase

wpa_passphrase=YourWiFiPassword

# Key management algorithms - set key and auth optionsmanagement

wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK

# Set cipher suites - TKIP and CCMP = AES in Counter mode with CBC-MAC

wpa_pairwise=TKIP

rsn_pairwise=CCMP

# Shared Key Authentication

auth_algs=1

# Accept all MAC address 

macaddr_acl=0
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, save file. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, close nano.

Now you can setup wlan0 in standalone mode or bridge it with eth0

```
$ sudo -i
# nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Modify or set config as follows:

```
auto lo br0

iface lo inet loopback

# wireless wlan0

allow-hotplug wlan0

iface wlan0 inet manual

# eth0 connected to the ISP router

allow-hotplug eth0

iface eth0 inet manual

# Setup bridge

iface br0 inet static

bridge_ports wlan0 eth0

address 10.160.10.11

netmask 255.255.255.0

network 10.160.10.0

#Isp Router IP, 10.160.10.2 also runs DHCPD

gateway 10.160.10.2

dns-nameservers 10.160.10.2
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, save file. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, close nano.

Reboot and make sure firewall is not blocking required ports:

```
$ sudo -i
# /sbin/iptables -L -n -v | less
```

Comment: I have already tried this with the correct drivers but I cannot connect to the network it creates. I know I properly set up dhcpd and set the interface to static but regardless it does not connect

Comment: That's not NetworkManager, it's a bare hostapd configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the network-manager indicator and select "create new wifi network" from the dropdown menu.
I first selected the wlan1 card and named the network "pineapples".
I have it set to ad-hoc and under ipv4 it's set to "share connection with other computers", no security.

Also, I clicked to connect from the chromebook while "pineapples" was still resolving as soon as the network appeared; then, the two computers connected to each other.

If the laptop drops or doesn't connect to "pineapples", it should still be listed as an available network from the network-manager dropdown list. Click on "pineapples" and while it is resolving, connect to "pineapples" from the other device.

At first, nothing would resolve but I clicked on my wlan0 network to reset the connection to the router and now both computers have internet.

Comment: Nothing happens when I hit create new wifi network. It just asks for Network name, and the password. Then I hit create but nothing happens.